# Minimizing rounding errors in a sum of floats

Tags: floating-point, numerical-methods, rounding-error

Column A contains floats that are rounded to two decimals. Column B contains float multipliers that should sum to ~1.00. Cn is calculated as ATOTAL * Bn - An. Column C contains floats rounded to two decimals, with the rounding error shown in brackets. The last row contains the values of the column summed.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.28 | 0.04184615384615385 | 1.43 (+0.003599999999998) |
| 6.68 | 0.364923076923077 | 8.26 (+0.003600000000003) |
| 14.7 | 0.28307692307692307 | -3.11 (+0.002000000000001) |
| 13.41 | 0.2793846153846154 | -1.97 (+0.000800000000001) |
| 2.65 | 0.00 | -2.65 (+0.00) |
| 3.23 | 0.03076923076923077 | -1.97 (+0.000000000000001) |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 (+0.00) |
| **TOTAL: 40.95** | **TOTAL: 1.00000000000000009** | **TOTAL: -0.01 (+0.010000000000004)** |

The goal is to have column C (with values rounded to two decimals) sum to exactly zero. However because of the rounding in C, each value creates a rounding error that can add up so that the sum isn't zero anymore. I'm trying to find a way to eliminate or minimize this rounding error in the sum of C.

- The way C is calculated can not be adjusted
- The rounding precision in any of the columns can not be adjusted

Is there any kind of calculation available to help reduce the rounding error in the sum of C by adjusting the values of A and B?

Comment: Re “…help reduce the rounding error in the sum of C by adjusting the values of A and B?”: If you adjust all the A values to zero or all the B values to zero, there will be no rounding errors. Perhaps you would like to set some constraints on the problem.

Comment: Consider the case where A contains 1, 1, and 1, with total 3, and B contains ⅓, ⅓, and ⅓ (or as close as can be represented). Then C will contain .33, .33, and .33, with total .99. Now observe that any adjustments you make to A or B to make C total 1 will break symmetry—it is impossible to have three identical two-decimal-digit numbers that sum to 1.00. You could make them .33, .33, and .34, but is that acceptable? How will you choose which one?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any kind of calculation available to help reduce the rounding error in the sum of C by adjusting the values of A and B?

The "error" is in the 7 roundings done via `round_to_nearest(ATOTAL * Bn - An, 0.01)`.

Given:

- "way C is calculated can not be adjusted"
- "rounding precision in any of the columns can not be adjusted"
- "adjusting the values of A and B"
- "A contains floats that are rounded to two decimals"

I see the only thing left is to adjust the `B` values as adjusting `A` is too course.  We have wiggle room given the `~` in "Column B contains float multipliers that should sum to ~1.00".

I propose scaling the B values by a value near 1.0

```
        Scale   1.00017451502617    
                
    A       B original          B scaled            C
    0.28    0.0418461538461539  0.0418534566287873   1.43
    6.68    0.364923076923077   0.364986761483395    8.27
    14.7    0.283076923076923   0.283126324253561   -3.11
    13.41   0.279384615384615   0.27943337219808    -1.97
    2.65    0                   0                   -2.65
    3.23    0.0307692307692308  0.0307746004623436  -1.97
    0       0                   0                    0
SUM 40.95   1                   1.00017451502617     0
```

Notice the sum of `B scaled` values rounds to 1.00, thus fulfilling "sum to ~1.00" in this case.

So the question remain: how to get the `scale`, 1.00017451502617 in this case?

This value was derived via Excel and "Solver".

Code can find this `scale` in various ways.

I suggest assuming the `scale` is between 0.9 and 1.1 and those values form  `total_C(0.9)` and `total_C(1.1)`, one above and the other below 0.0.  Then use a bisection search on `scale` to find a better `total_C`.

---

To avoid conundrums like [@Eric Postpischi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75405326/minimizing-rounding-errors-in-a-sum-of-floats/75406530#comment133051814_75405326), we can add a small (perhaps random) offset to each `B` as used in calculation proposes: `B_prime = B + 0.000001*offset*line#` to help deal with stubborn cases where an exact `total_C` of 0.0 is not initially found in the bisection.

Code may still fail to solve for all `A`, `B` values, but with carefully coding and some wiggle in the `B` values used, it should be rare.